# Как запретить дочернему элементу выходить за границы родителя?

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте. Делаю мини чатик, но есть проблема. Если сообщение длинное и без переносов через enter то блок с текстом вылазит за пределы контейнера для сообщений. Как можно решить эту проблему? Спасибо.

[image: скрин]

Comment: Дубликат то дубликат, но здесь ответ пополнее, поэтому может оставить

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например с помощью [word-wrap: break-word;](https://webref.ru/css/word-wrap)

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
</div>
```

P.S: Вариант 2 для конкретно вашего примера с `display: inline-flex;`

```css
.divStyles {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  word-break: break-word; /* doesn't work in firefox */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 200px;
  
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="divStyles">
  testttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
</div>
```

Comment: попробовал но нету эфекта, в чем может быть проблема?
![скрин](https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/07/f141a88828b716d9249480b5412e7606.png)

Comment: Эм.. А flex-то тут при чём?

Comment: @Qwertiy, скрин из комментария выше посмотрите. Одного `word-wrap: break-word;` для `display: inline-flex;` недлостаточно

Comment: `word-break: break-word; word-wrap: break-word;` - этого достаточно без flexbox'а же?

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать word-break

```css
.chat {
background:#f4f4f4;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #666;
color:#666;
padding:10px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
.message {

background:#00AAFF;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #005B88;
color:#005B88;
word-break:break-word;
box-sizing:border-box;

padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
<div class="message">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextv</div>
</div>
```

Comment: С `break-all` даже обычные слова будут разрываться вместо переноса.